# Java Spring adding model to ModelAndView throws StackOverflowException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there any way to prevent StackOverflowException when adding model into modelandview?

I have a method that returns a modelandview but I've seen that if I try to add model to modelandview it throws and StackOverflowException because Model already has modelandview, is there any way to add it without need to remove modelandview from model first?

```
    ((BindingAwareModelMap) model).remove("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.modelAndView");
    ((BindingAwareModelMap) model).remove("modelAndView");
    modelAndView.addObject(model);
    return modelAndView;
```

Comment: Why? What you are basically doing is adding the model to itself, which eventually will (as you noticed) lead to a stackoverflow when preparing the request. So don't do this.

Comment: My AJAX is expecting a xhr status along the view, this is why I need to return modelandview and not just a view.

Comment: Where do I state that you cannot use a `ModelAndView`? But what you are doing is wrong, you are adding the model to the modelandview, and you are basically adding hte model to itself. `ModelAndView.addObject` will add that object to the model. Now what you are adding is the model. So you are basically doing `model.add(model)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ModelAndView`, Spring does not expect you to manually create a `Model`.

Spring expects that you set the attributes that you want for model to have directly on the model object contained inside `ModelAndView`.

So it should be

```
modelAndView.getModel().put("attribute1", object1);
modelAndView.getModel().put("attribute2", object2);
```